# Restrict Preloader to Parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

**[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/devin1229/pen/vYZyWPE)**

In the above Codepen/ following code snippet , I have a multi-step form with a preloader that appears before displaying the results. Right now it takes up the entire viewport - I'm trying to contain it to just the form box.

If I move it into the form (prior to `</form>`), it loads below the results instead of on top. I've also tried changed the form's `position` to `absolute` and then relying on the preloader's `position: relative` attribute, but that doesn't work either.

Any thoughts on getting this to display just within the form area?

```js
let step = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
let prevBtn = document.getElementById("prev-btn");
let nextBtn = document.getElementById("next-btn");
let submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit-btn");
let form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
let bodyElement = document.querySelector("body");
let preloader = document.getElementById("form-preloader-pagewrap");
let successDiv = document.getElementById("results");
let resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset-btn");

form.onSubmit = () => {
  return false;
};

let current_step = 0;
let stepCount = 3;
step[current_step].classList.add("hidden");
if (current_step == 0) {
  prevBtn.classList.add("hidden");
  submitBtn.classList.add("hidden");
  nextBtn.classList.add("show");
}

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  current_step++;
  let previous_step = current_step - 1;
  if (current_step > 0 && current_step <= stepCount) {
    prevBtn.classList.remove("hidden");
    prevBtn.classList.add("show");
    step[current_step].classList.remove("hidden");
    step[current_step].classList.add("show");
    step[previous_step].classList.remove("show");
    step[previous_step].classList.add("hidden");
    if (current_step == stepCount) {
      submitBtn.classList.remove("hidden");
      submitBtn.classList.add("show");
      nextBtn.classList.remove("show");
      nextBtn.classList.add("hidden");
    }
  } else {
    if (current_step > stepCount) {
      form.onSubmit = () => {
        return true;
      };
    }
  }
});

prevBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (current_step > 0) {
    current_step--;
    let previous_step = current_step + 1;
    prevBtn.classList.add("hidden");
    prevBtn.classList.add("show");
    step[current_step].classList.remove("hidden");
    step[current_step].classList.add("show");
    step[previous_step].classList.remove("show");
    step[previous_step].classList.add("hidden");
    if (current_step < stepCount) {
      submitBtn.classList.remove("show");
      submitBtn.classList.add("hidden");
      nextBtn.classList.remove("hidden");
      nextBtn.classList.add("show");
      prevBtn.classList.remove("hidden");
      prevBtn.classList.add("show");
    }
  }

  if (current_step == 0) {
    prevBtn.classList.remove("show");
    prevBtn.classList.add("hidden");
  }
});

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  preloader.classList.add("show");

  const timer = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

  timer(3000)
    .then(() => {
      bodyElement.classList.add("loaded");
    })
    .then(() => {
      step[stepCount].classList.remove("show");
      step[stepCount].classList.add("hidden");
      prevBtn.classList.remove("show");
      prevBtn.classList.add("hidden");
      submitBtn.classList.remove("show");
      submitBtn.classList.add("hidden");
      successDiv.classList.remove("hidden");
      successDiv.classList.add("show");
    });

  var cards = $(".results-card");

  function filterCards() {
    var checked = $(".step :checkbox:checked");
    if (checked.length) {
      cards.hide();
      checked.each(function () {
        $("." + $(this).val()).fadeIn(500);
      });
    } else {
      cards.fadeIn(500);
    }
  }

  $(".step :checkbox").click(filterCards);
  filterCards();
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

form {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 350px;
}

#form-preloader-pagewrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 350px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#form-preloader {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.loaded #form-preloader-pagewrap {
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: all 0.3s 1s ease-out;
}

.loaded #form-preloader {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.results-cards-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.results-card {
  flex: 0 1 24%;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px dotted #1e1e1e;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="step show">Form Introduction</div>

  <div class="step hidden">
    Step 1<br>
    <input id="a" type="checkbox" value="a"><label for="a">A</label>
  </div>

  <div class="step hidden">
    Step 2<br>
    <input id="b" type="checkbox" value="b"><label for="b">B</label>
  </div>

  <div class="step hidden">
    Step 3<br>
    <input id="c" type="checkbox" value="c"><label for="c">C</label>
  </div>

  <div id="results" class="hidden">
    <div class="results-cards-container">
      <div class="results-card a b">A,B</div>
      <div class="results-card a">A</div>
      <div class="results-card a">A</div>
      <div class="results-card b">B</div>
      <div class="results-card b">B</div>
      <div class="results-card b">B</div>
      <div class="results-card c">C</div>
    </div>

    <a href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href">Start Over</a>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="prev-btn" type="button">Previous</button>
    <button id="next-btn" type="button">Next</button>
    <button id="submit-btn" type="button">Submit</button>
  </div>

</form>

<div id="form-preloader-pagewrap" class="hidden">
  <div id="form-preloader" class="show">
    <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-8x" style="color: #fff"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

- Moving preloader div into the form
- Adding `position: relative` to the form
- Changing preloader to `position: absolute`

Modified Codepen: https://codepen.io/pawel7/pen/bGRBvpd.

Comment: I swear I tried that and it wasn't working! Ha ha. Thanks so much.